# SSIS Insert bulk failed due to a schema change of the target table

Tags: ssis

I am developing a SSIS package get the following error only in QA environment and not Dev environment. Not sure why I am getting an error saying there is schema change. Is it because of truncate table statements at the end of the stored procedures. I am running the SSIS package via SQL job in the QA. If the truncate was the problem they why didn't it have issues in Dev ?

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Insert bulk failed due to a schema change of the target table.".
>
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (29)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (29)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPartiesPremiumFinancials_SSIS]
/* pulls the information relating to the income statement, 
balance sheet and cash flow statement, including total employees
converts the historical data at the most recent spot rate*/
    @dataItemstring VARCHAR(MAX) = '2,7,21,15,28,34,75,97,208,373,400,1002,1004,1007,1008,1009,1012,1014,1018,1021,1043,1054,1085,1222,1275,1276,1310,1312,2004,2005,2006,2021,2055,2056,3058,3069,3523,4051,4173,4371,4377,35379,2021',
    @periodtypeId INT = 4
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @date DATE = '2016-01-01'

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
              WHERE object_id = object_id('dataItemId') AND NAME = 'idx_dataItemId')
        DROP INDEX idx_dataItemId ON dataItemId

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
              WHERE object_id = object_id('tempCompany') AND NAME = 'idx_tempCompany')
        DROP INDEX idx_tempCompany ON tempCompany

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
              WHERE object_id = object_id('EstPeriodTbl') AND NAME ='idx_EstPeriodTbl')
        DROP INDEX idx_EstPeriodTbl ON EstPeriodTbl

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
              WHERE object_id = object_id('maxDate') AND NAME ='idx_maxDate')
        DROP INDEX idx_maxDate ON maxDate

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
              WHERE object_id = object_id('currencyTbl') AND NAME = 'idx_currencyTbl')
        DROP INDEX idx_currencyTbl ON currencyTbl

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
              WHERE object_id = object_id('temp1') AND NAME ='idx_temp1')
        DROP INDEX idx_temp1 ON temp1

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
              WHERE object_id = object_id('PartiesPremiumFinancials') 
                AND NAME ='ix_PartiesPremiumFinancials_companyId')
    DROP INDEX ix_PartiesPremiumFinancials_companyId ON PartiesPremiumFinancials

    INSERT INTO dataItemId
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.splitstring(@dataItemstring)

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_dataItemId ON dataItemId(val)


    INSERT INTO tempCompany 
        SELECT
            fp.companyId, fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter,
            fi.financialperiodid, fi.periodEndDate,
            fc.currencyId, fp.periodtypeid, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fp.companyId, fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter ORDER BY fi.periodEndDate DESC) rowno 
        FROM
            ciqFinPeriod fp
        INNER JOIN 
            ciqcompany c ON c.companyId = fp.companyId
        JOIN 
            ciqFinInstance fi ON fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
        JOIN
            ciqFinInstanceToCollection ic ON ic.financialInstanceId = fi.financialInstanceId
        LEFT JOIN
            ciqFinCollection fc ON fc.financialCollectionId = ic.financialCollectionId
        LEFT JOIN
            ciqFinCollectionData fd ON fd.financialCollectionId = fc.financialCollectionId
        WHERE
            fp.periodTypeId = @periodtypeId
            AND fi.periodenddate >= @date

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_tempCompany ON tempCompany(rowno)


    INSERT INTO EstPeriodTbl 
        SELECT
            companyId, fiscalYear, fiscalQuarter,
            financialPeriodId, periodenddate, currencyId,
            periodtypeid, rowno
        FROM
            tempCompany a
        WHERE
            a.rowno = 1
        ORDER BY
            companyid, periodenddate

    /* finds the max pricing date for each table */
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_EstPeriodTbl ON EstPeriodTbl(companyId, periodenddate, fiscalYear, fiscalQuarter, currencyId, financialPeriodId, rowno)  

    INSERT INTO maxDate
        SELECT
            MAX(exr.pricingDate) AS pricingDate, 
            exr.currencyId
        FROM
            ciqExchangeRate exr
        INNER JOIN
            EstPeriodTbl ept ON ept.currencyId = exr.currencyId
        GROUP BY
            exr.currencyId

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_maxDate ON maxDate(pricingDate, currencyId)  


    INSERT INTO currencyTbl 
        SELECT 
            a.currencyId, b.pricingDate, a.CurrencyRateClose
        FROM
            ciqExchangeRate a
        INNER JOIN
            maxDate b ON a.currencyId = b.currencyId 
                      AND a.pricingDate = b.pricingDate
        ORDER BY 
            currencyID

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_currencyTbl 
        ON currencyTbl(currencyId, pricingDate, CurrencyRateClose)  

    /* combine the tables and convert into USD using the most recent pricing date, if a goforward estimate*/


    INSERT INTO temp1 
        SELECT
            a.companyId,
            fd.dataItemId,
            di.dataItemName,
            dataItemvalue = CASE WHEN fd.unitTypeId = 0 
                                    THEN fd.dataitemvalue
                                 WHEN fd.unitTypeId = 1 
                                    THEN fd.dataitemvalue * 1e3 
                                 ELSE fd.dataitemvalue * 1e6 
                            END,
            a.fiscalYear, a.fiscalQuarter, a.periodenddate,
            fc.currencyId, a.periodTypeId
        FROM
            EstPeriodTbl a
        JOIN
            ciqFinInstance fi ON fi.financialPeriodId = a.financialPeriodId
        JOIN
            ciqFinInstanceToCollection ic ON ic.financialInstanceId = fi.financialInstanceId
        INNER JOIN
            ciqFinCollection fc ON fc.financialCollectionId = ic.financialCollectionId
        INNER JOIN
            ciqFinCollectionData fd ON fd.financialCollectionId = fc.financialCollectionId
        INNER JOIN
            dataItemId d ON d.val = fd.dataItemId
        INNER JOIN
            ciqDataItem di ON di.dataItemId = fd.dataItemId
        --join #currencyTbl ex on (ex.currencyId = a.currencyId)
        WHERE
            --fd.dataitemid in (select val from @dataitemid)
            fi.latestForFinancialPeriodFlag = 1 -- flag indicating that this instance is the latest one for the financial period
            AND fi.latestFilingforInstanceFlag = 1 -- flag considers any restatements
        ORDER BY
            a.companyId DESC, dataitemid ASC, a.fiscalYear DESC, a.fiscalQuarter DESC

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_temp1 
        ON temp1 (companyId, dataItemId, fiscalYear, fiscalQuarter, currencyId)  

    SELECT
        a.companyId,
        a.dataItemId, a.dataItemName,
        dataItemvalueUSD = CASE WHEN conv.currencyConversionFlag  = 1 
                                   THEN a.dataItemValue / ex.currencyRateClose 
                                   ELSE a.dataItemValue 
                           END, 
        a.fiscalYear, a.fiscalQuarter,
        a.currencyId, a.periodEndDate, a.periodTypeId 
    FROM
        temp1 a
    JOIN
        currencyTbl ex ON ex.currencyId = a.currencyId
    INNER JOIN
        ciqDataItemConversionRule conv ON conv.dataItemId = a.dataItemId
    ORDER BY
        a.companyId DESC, a.dataitemid ASC, a.fiscalYear DESC, a.fiscalQuarter DESC


    truncate table [dbo].[dataItemId];
    truncate table [dbo].[tempCompany];
    truncate table [dbo].[EstPeriodTbl];
    truncate table [dbo].[maxDate];
    truncate table [dbo].[currencyTbl];
    truncate table [dbo].[temp1];

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_PartiesPremiumFinancials_companyId 
        ON CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.PartiesPremiumFinancials (companyId, dataItemId, dataItemName, dataItemvalueUSD, fiscalYear, fiscalQuarter, currencyId, periodEndDate, periodtypeId) 
END
```

Comment: Never do an insert without specifying the field names in the insert. This is a an accident waiting to happen as things change over time. Code written as you have is a huge SQL antipattern..

Comment: Most likely the problems is that the dev and QA tables do not have the same structure.

Comment: The tables that I am writing to is the same structure.

Comment: why are you truncating tables after just inserting into them? Truncate, BTW does not change the structure of the table and I use it in scripts all the time without a problem. I am not seeing the bulk insert. Is there a trigger by chance on one of these tables?

Comment: I am using those tables as temp tables though they are physical tables. Have done that to improve performance which it actually did. This  storeproc pulls nearly 8 million records

Comment: No trigger is used

Comment: So my SSIS package queries this in the source and dumps the results in a destination table in another database as a table

Comment: Can you show us anything that proves that the tables in DEV and QA all have the same structure?   Because the most likely explanation is that you're wrong about that.   Currently your question is not reproducible, and therefore not really answerable.